# Data structure that would best suite for a phone book

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures

I know it is repeated, but I am really getting mixed answers.
Some say Hash table, but for hash table, if there are two names then how would it be unique or it would be unique with key?

Which data structure should I use?

I want to look up by phone number and name as well. The phone book is quite large too.

Comment: What kind of look-ups do you want to do? Look-up a name for a phone number or look-up a phone number for a name? or both?

Comment: It depends on your requirements.  If you were actually writing a phonebook, you would probably have a dedicated machine or cluster running a properly indexed database.  If it's for an algorithms and data structures course, it depends on what you've covered.  Maybe a balanced Binary Search Tree?

Comment: @TheEvilPenguin data structure only..why binary search tree ? phone book is very large

Comment: @user2387900 We don't know anything about your requirements or what you've learned.  A balanced BST is space efficient and inherently ordered while still having fairly good (and predictable) insertion and lookup, while with a hash table things can get inefficient unless you do a good job of guessing the size in advance - the underlying container may need to resize multiple times.  It can also be difficult to get anything ordered out of a hash table, and I guess for a phone book you'll need to sort by name.  BSTs also handle duplicates while you need to go to more effort with a hash table.

Comment: You don't need to worry about your data structure.  You're not going to be loading the whole thing in to memory anyway.  Store it in a DB.  Retrieve what you want to quickly by putting indexes on the columns you can retrieve by (name and phone number).  Store the results in a List<Address>, or Address[] or DataTable or whatever (where address is a name/phone number combination object you define.)  The data structure you're storing it in in memory is not really relevant since you've already done the search in the db.  No fancy data structure required.

Comment: if this is homework: a hash table. if this is not homework: a database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A phone book would likely be fairly large, and not require having all items in memory at once.  As such, it seems like it would be better suited to storage within a database, with indexes as required for quick retrieval by name.

Comment: Which Data structure should i use ? @reed

Comment: @user2387900 Depends on what you're doing.  But chances are good that you don't need much in the way of a data structure to hold the data because you're only reading in a few elements of the phone book at a time.  You can't really display a whole phonebook in a web page or on a program screen; you can only display a few names/addresses at a time.  Read in those few names/addresses from the db, and put them in anything...a List, an array, whatever.  At that point the data structure doesn't matter so much, so long as you can iterate through it.

Comment: If this is a practical application and not just a way to learn more about data structures, this is absolutely the way to go.  Databases are a well-researched and well-developed technology, so there's no need to reinvent the Rolodex.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very confused question, because it isn't about data structures.  Give each entry a unique ID (look up UUID for examples).  Beyond that, the data structure you use depends on the data you are holding your 'phone book.

Comment: I need to retrieve on the base of name or phone number, so index wont be proper. Which data structure you suggest ?

Comment: In-memory I would suggest that you use a multimap for both names and numbers, as neither are unique to a single entry.  On-disk depends on your datastore (SQL or NoSQL).

Answer (score 0):

Use [Surrogate key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) technique to have unique ID, so you can use hashtable, key can be generated as [GUID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx)

You can use ordinary arrays too, so just array of structures, so index in array will be your unique key

Comment: phone book is very large but.

Comment: then it is better to use any kind of database, MSSQL provides surrogate keys via identity property http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196(v=sql.80).aspx

structure can be very simple, like "id, name, phone", maybe split name for first and last, phone is better to store as numbers and maybe + sign, so remove any useless symbols like - (space) ( and )